# SQL for finding types that have all ids on some row

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I am working with SQL queries in ACCESS 2010 and I have a table that looks something like this:

```
Mytable
ID  |  TYPE
1   |  a
1   |  b
2   |  a
2   |  a
3   |  a
3   |  b
3   |  c
```

And I want to return all types that matches with every ID at least once.
So in this case only `a` will be return since its the only type represented on a row with `1`,`2` and `3`.

Help greatly appreciated!

Comment: It would be helpful for you to include what you have tried.

Comment: Ohh well nothing I've done has come remotely close i think. I have been looking into Relational Division and using double `WHERE NOT EXISTS` but this problem is not really suited for that.[link](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)
Thanks for replying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regular SQL, you could write:

```
select type
from mytable 
group by type
having count(distinct id) = (select count(distinct id) from mytable);
```

That will not quite work in MS Access because Access does not support `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.

But, if we assume no duplicates in `mytable`, then this variant should work:

```
select type
from mytable
group by type
having count(*) = (select count(*)
                   from (select distinct id from mytable) as t
                  );
```

EDIT:

If the table could contain duplicates, then you can remove them before the aggregation:

```
select type
from (select distinct type, id from mytable ) as ti
group by type
having count(*) = (select count(*)
                   from (select distinct id from mytable) as t
                  );
```

Comment: This returns no values. Will not `count(*)` give the number of total rows containing a type?
The table may contain duplicates.
 I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Yes this solved my problem! Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you could approach it; the sub query returns all ID's that occur atleast twice, and then you join on all the values that exist for those ID's.

```
SELECT a.ID, b.TYPE
FROM 
(
    SELECT ID 
    FROM Mytable 
    GROUP BY ID 
    HAVING COUNT(ID) > 1
) a
INNER JOIN Mytable b ON b.ID = a.ID
```